# How would you extract the data in an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, format, output

can anyone tell me how I would format and break down the data in this `php` array so I can format it with `html`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [domain] => maxmymaxmymax.com
        [result] => AVAILABLE
        [reason] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: `$arr[0]->domain` and `$arr[0]->result`.

Comment: Or can use it as `$arr[0]['domain']` and `$arr[0]['result']`

Comment: @NarendraSisodia your suggestion is not true and will not work. the outer object is of array thus `$arr[0]` can be used. But the inner objects are class objects. so thus you need to use `$arr[0]->domain`. Do not get confused.

Answer (score 0):

your output is object type 
so Just typecast it like below

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

Comment: would if I wanted to print just the value of  domain in the array

Answer (score 0):

use like this and you will get an array

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($object);
$array = $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
```